# Wie heißt das literarische Mittel: Ein Objekt wird dauernd erwähnt, taucht aber nicht auf

Tags: literature

Wie wird das literarische Mittel genannt, wenn von einem Objekt (oder einer Person) immer wieder die Rede ist, das Objekt (oder die Person) allerdings niemals auftaucht.
Als Beispiel könnte ich nur das Werk "Warten auf Godot" nennen, in dem die Person Godot ständig erwähnt wird, allerdings nicht auftaucht.

Comment: Gute Frage! "Beschwören" oder gar "ständiges Beschwören" kommt mir in den Sinn. "Beredtes Beschweigen" wäre dann wohl das Gegenteil.

Comment: tvtropes.com nennt diese Figur "The Ghost", wenn es sich um eine Person handelt und liefert eine Reihe von Beispielen: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheGhost

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Es gibt wahrscheinlich mehr Interpretationen von Beckets "Warten auf Godot" als es vergleichende Literaturwissenschaftler gibt. Eine der Möglichkeiten, sich dem Stück zu nähern, ist die rein formalistische. Danach würde die Handlung (oder Nicht-Handlung) auf nichts außerhalb des Theaters verweisen, insbesondere keine Aussagen zu Nihilismus, zum Sinn des Lebens oder sonstigen philosophischen Fragen machen und erst recht nicht politische Themen anschneiden. Das Stück wäre dann ein einziger langer Insider-Witz, in dem eine Anspielung auf Theaterstücke und Literarisches die nächste jagt.

User "musiKk" hat bereits den "MacGuffin" erwähnt. Der **[red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)**, der in der Literatur zur Irreführung des Lesers verwendet wird, ist eine weitere Technik, die von Romanautoren und Dramatikern eingesetzt wird. Allerdings wird die **falsche Fährte** früher oder später beiseitegelegt, wenn die Handlung auf die Auflösung zusteuert. Die bei Beckett verweigerte Auflösung erinnert an Richard Wagners [Tristan-Akkord](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tristan-Akkord), der die Erwartung des Hörers auf eindeutige Einbettung in einen funktionsharmonischen Zusammenhang düpiert.

Außerdem wäre noch an Tschechow und seine Maxime zu denken, wonach eine geladene Pistole, die im 1. Akt gezeigt wurde, unbedingt im Verlauf des Stückes abgefeuert werden muss, ansonsten man sie gefälligst gleich wegzulassen habe ("**epische Vorausdeutung**"). Beckett macht sich über diese mechanische Auffassung lustig, indem er den bis aufs äußerste gespannten Theatergast auf die Auflösung warten lässt, diese dann aber verweigert. Nach dieser Interpretation wäre Beckett dann ein Anarchist, der gegen die Einzwängung von Theaterautor und Zuschauer durch das klappernde Räderwerk der "plot devices" aufbegehrt. "Wenn man vom Teufel spricht--" kommt er gerade nicht, so könnte man ergänzen.

Schließlich wäre an die uralte Tradition des [**Deus ex machina**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deus_ex_machina) im Theater zu denken. Das Warten auf Godot durch Wladimir und Estragon und seine **Anrufung** -- die beschwörende Nennung seines Namens -- wären dann ein Spiel mit der Erwartung auf das "überraschende" Aufsteigen des Gottes aus dem Bühnenboden unter Donner und Rauch, das ja schon zu Euripides' Zeiten nur schlichtere Gemüter schockieren konnte. Natürlich haben schon zu Zeiten der Erstaufführung manche an eine nietzscheanische Interpretation gedacht -- "Gott ist tot" -- oder an eine jüdische -- Warten auf den Messias -- aber Beckett hat zeit seines Lebens allen Versuchen widerstanden, diese Auffassungen zu bestätigen oder zu widerlegen. Damit hat er die Nicht-Auflösung der Spannung im Stück für immer festgeschrieben.

Jedoch war Beckett nicht der erste Theaterautor, der in einem Stück eine **abwesende Figur** auftreten lässt. Beispiele u.a. Tartüff, der erst zur Hälfte des Stückes die Bühne betritt, obwohl von ihm zuvor ständig die Rede ist. Überhaupt nicht treten auf in Eugene O'Neills "Desire Under the Elms" die zentrale Figur der Mutter und in Sophokles' "Ödipus Rex" der Königsvater Laios; allerdings sind beide bereits verstorben, im Gegensatz zu Godot (so er existiert).<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)</sup>

Neben dem abwesenden Ding oder McGuffin und der abwesenden Figur gibt es noch die Abwesenheit von etwas Immateriellen. Das kann etwas Ersehntes sein, ein Objekt der Begierde. So können gerade bei Tscheschow alle Figuren das ganze Stück lang dem Glück hinterherlaufen, ohne mehr als einen Zipfel zu erhaschen. Als Überbegriff für alle diese Abwesenheiten wäre vielleicht die **Leerstelle** geeignet, die vom Autor auf je eigene Weise umschrieben, aber nie gefüllt wird.

<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring)</sup> http://www.iasj.net/iasj?func=fulltext&aId=43354

Answer (score 5):

Ich kenne diesen Begriff nur für die Filmszene. Dort heißt es [MacGuffin](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin). Da *Warten auf Godot* ein Theaterstück ist, kann man diesen aber vielleicht auch verwenden.

Comment: Nun ja, ein McGuffin kann durchaus auftauchen, siehe z.B. der Koffer in Pulp Fiction. Es wird nur nicht erklärt, was seine tiefere Bedeutung ist. Es ist einfach nur ein Platzhalter, eine Projektionsfläche für den zuschauer, der sich selber zusammenreimen kann, was die Signifikanz des Objekts ist, ohne vom Drehbuch den geringsten Anhaltspunkt dafür zu bekommen.

Comment: In dem Zusammenhang kann man wohl auch von *Aufhänger* reden.

Comment: MacGuffin ist ein tolles Stichwort zu diesem Thema, danke! Aber leider ist es nicht exakt was ich meine wie mein Vorredner bereits anmerkte!

Comment: @Em1: `Aufhänger` ist viel weniger spezifisch, denn der Begriff schließt weder aus, dass dem Zuschauer näheres bekannt ist ('Aufhänger ist der Ausbruch d. II Weltkriegs'), noch, dass sich die Bedeutung im Laufe der Handlung enthüllt.